# Vue-strap with Laravel: Module build failed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-strap

I'm not sure if Vue-strap works with 2.0 so I want to try using its Navbar component.

I add this in app.js.

```
Vue.component('navbar', require('../../../node_modules/vue-strap/src/Navbar.vue'));
```

gulp watch throws this error.

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-strap/src/utils/NodeList.js
Module build failed: Error
  at ForOfStatement.initialise (/var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:2004:65)
at /var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:9381:56
at Array.forEach (native)
at BlockStatement.initialise (/var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:9381:15)
at FunctionDeclaration.initialise (/var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:858:12)
at FunctionDeclaration.initialise (/var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:2071:31)
at /var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:9381:56
at Array.forEach (native)
at BlockStatement.initialise (/var/www/web_redeem/node_modules/buble/dist/buble.umd.js:9381:15)
@ ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./~/vue-strap/src/Navbar.vue 33:0-35
@ ./~/vue-strap/src/Navbar.vue
@ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Elixir compiles js with Bublé that does not support `for ... of` statements yet. Consider switching to babel instead.

If you are you using https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2 change to https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vue